# Sort a nested array of object when index is a key in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to sort nested array of objects, based off the key hours. The reason I am setting the index as userId, is that I want to be able to do highScoreList[userId] at a later time to grab the selected user information.

```
[
 '587665723162626': { userId: '587665723162626', hours: 0, lastHours: 0 },
 '120156769943556': { userId: '120156769943556', hours: 0, lastHours: 0 },
 '773193626386432': { userId: '773193626386432', hours: 10, lastHours: 2 }
]
```

```
    let highScoreList = [];
    //data is inserted via another function from mongoDB and below is how I inserted into the array.
    const updateHighScoreCache = (userId, hours, lastHours) =>{
        highScoreList[userId] = { userId, hours, lastHours };
    }
            
    function compare(a, b) {
        if(a.hours > b.hours) return 1;
        if(b.hours > a.hours) return -1;
        return 0;
    }
    highScoreList.sort(compare)
```

I have tried changing the if statement in the compare function to the following and the array did not change at all still:

```
   if(highScoreList[a].hours > highScoreList[b].hours) return 1;
   if(highScoreList[b].hours > highScoreList[a].hours) return -1;
```

The expected result after sort is:

```
[
 '773193626386432': { userId: '773193626386432', hours: 10, lastHours: 2 },
 '587665723162626': { userId: '587665723162626', hours: 0, lastHours: 0 },
 '120156769943556': { userId: '120156769943556', hours: 0, lastHours: 0 }
]
```

But I keep getting the original array.

Comment: The syntax of your "array" at the top is not valid. Arrays literals don't have named keys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your array literal at the top is not valid JS syntax. The code shows where you go wrong.

First you define `highScoreList` as an array, but then you don't populate the array, but create object properties for it, with:

```
highScoreList[userId] = { userId, hours, lastHours };
```

These (non-index) properties are ignored by the typical array methods such as `sort`. Those methods work on the values stored at the array *indexes*.

So change this:

```
highScoreList[userId] = { userId, hours, lastHours };
```

to this:

```
highScoreList.push({ userId, hours, lastHours });
```

If however, the structure is returned to you as a plain object (not an array), like so:

```
{
  '587665723162626': { userId: '587665723162626', hours: 0, lastHours: 0 },
  '120156769943556': { userId: '120156769943556', hours: 0, lastHours: 0 },
  '773193626386432': { userId: '773193626386432', hours: 10, lastHours: 2 }
}
```

..then note that plain objects are not really the right tool for *sorting*. They better serve use cases where you don't care about order. So if you really get an object like this (not an array) and need order, then covert that object to an array first, with:

```
highScoreList = Object.values(highScoreList);
```

...and then call `.sort`

**Another remark:** your `compare` function will do the job, but the way it really is done, is as follows:

```
const compare = (a, b) => a.hours - b.hours;
```

Comment: Thanks! Originally I had it as an object, and was using Object.keys(highScoreList).sort and that didn't work so I changed to an array afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

If you array is:

```
const highScoreList = [
 { userId: '587665723162626', hours: 0, lastHours: 0 },
 { userId: '120156769943556', hours: 0, lastHours: 0 },
 { userId: '773193626386432', hours: 10, lastHours: 2 }
];
```

Then this code sorts it DESC:

```
highScoreList.sort((x,y) => y.hours - x.hours)
```

Then this code sorts it ASC:

```
highScoreList.sort((x,y) => x.hours - y.hours)
```